# Integrating more than one function error in python

Tags: python, scipy, typeerror, ipython, numerical-integration

Lets say i define my function G,

```
def G(k, P, W):
    return k**2*P*W**2
```

Where P and W are two functions that have independent variables of k and k is a defined number.

I am trying to integrate this from 0 to infinity

```
I = scipy.integrate.quad(G, 0, np.Inf)
```

inputting this into my console gives me the error,
`G() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`

I tried using the `arg()` command, but it does not seem to change it and code remains stubborn. What am i doing wrong and what am i missing?

Comment: It would be helpful to mention what `integrate.quad` function you are talking about.

Comment: So `P = P(k)` and `W = W(k)` but you **don't** want to integrate over these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, k is a constant. Then you can write:

```
k = 10
I = integrate.dblquad(lambda p,w: G(k,p,w), 0, np.Inf, lambda x: 0, lambda x: np.Inf)
```

Found it in the [scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html).

Besides, your integral looks divergent.

For symbolic integrals see [sympy.integrate](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html). It is a different library.

```
import * from sympy

k,P,W = symbols('k P W')
integrate(G(k,P,W),P,W)
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. I would not have known to use that.